# How to display double without exponential?

Tags: c, printf

I am printing output of a timer which is double.

I am getting **1.84e-308** as output.

I am printing with `printf("Time: %4.3g\n",tm.getTime());`

Comment: **1.84e-308** without exponential is (approximately) `0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 0000000000000000000000000184` (ignore spaces inserted for formatting)

Comment: and what output is your desire? 0.000000...0000000184?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `%f`?

```
printf("Time: %4.3f\n",tm.getTime())
```

Comment: @AJ. That is a very very tiny number, very very *very* close to 0, so 0.00 is not unexpected here.

Answer (score 0):

`printf("Time: %400.399f\n",tm.getTime())`

Yes?

Answer (score -1):

Here, You have to change data type format as double. Write coding as mentioned below:

> **printf("Time: %4.3g\n",tm.getTime(double_variable))**

You can get 1.84e-308 from above coding.